# DGN Version 8 Format Specification

Tags: qgis, gdal, microstation, dgn

I tried to open a Microstation DGN version 8 file with QGIS/ogrinfo, but GDAL/OGR supports Version 7 only.  So I want to write my own parser by looking at the format of DGN.

Is the Microstation DGN version 8 format specification available publicly ?

Answer (score 1):

The V8 format is proprietary. However Bentley have teamed up with the Open Design Alliance (www.opendesign.com) who provide commercial libraries for reading and writing DGN V8 and DWG CAD file formats.